# SceneKit View reset when using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I'm actually facing an issue using SceneKit with SwiftUI. I'm working on a Mac app that show a USDZ model in a SCNScene with some SwiftUI buttons and stuff on the same HStack.

My SCNScene is resetting every time i use other SwiftUI items and I can't figure why.
I tried directly with a SceneView and with a SceneKitViewRepresentable and I got the same result.
When using SwiftUI items like Buttons, the camera reset and if the model is showed it disappear.

```
struct SceneModelView: View {

@Binding var modelUrl: URL?
@ObservedObject var sceneVM = SceneViewModel()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        SceneView(scene: sceneVM.scene, pointOfView: .none, options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl], preferredFramesPerSecond: 60)
        if modelUrl != nil {
            Rectangle()
                .opacity(0)
                .onAppear {
                    sceneVM.addModelToScene(url: modelUrl!)
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    sceneVM.removeModelToScene()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I call this View in the main HStack.

```
class SceneViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var scene = SCNScene()
    @Published var modelNode: SCNReferenceNode? = nil
    
    init() {
        guard let newScene = SCNScene(named: "ModelScene.scn") else { return }
        scene = newScene
        scene.background.contents = NSColor.gray
    }
    
    func addModelToScene(url: URL) {
        createModelFromUrl(url: url)
        if modelNode != nil {
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelNode!)
        }
    }
    
    func removeModelToScene() {
        if modelNode != nil {
            modelNode!.removeFromParentNode()
        }
    }
    
    private func createModelFromUrl(url: URL) {
        modelNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: url)
        if modelNode != nil {
            modelNode!.load()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ViewModel.
I'm using Xcode 13.0 beta with macOS Monterey.

Comment: Try to use StateObject instead of ObservedObject.

Comment: Simple at that, thank you !